# Upper Topology on R

Tags: general-topology

I need help proving that the upper topology on ${\bf R}$ is in fact a topology. The upper topology is generated by the basis $\{(a,\infty)\mid a \in  {\bf R} \cup (-\infty,\infty)\}$

I think I can see that ${\bf R}$ and the empty set are in the topology. Is it true for ${\bf R}$ when $a=-\infty$ and true for the empty set when $a=\infty$?

I am having problems proving that the union and intersections are in the topology.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you calculate the intersection of $(a,\infty)$ and $(b,\infty)$?

Comment: it is just (a,b), right?

Comment: No, that's not right. Every nonempty open set contains _all_ large enough numbers.

Comment: What about $(42,\infty)\cap (0,\infty)$? Is it $(0,42)$ (or $(42,0)$)?

Comment: Well, I would say (0,42), but based on that my answer before was wrong, I'm not certain.

Comment: On the union part, does it work to say something like this: 
If you have $(x_1,\infty)U(x_2,\infty)U(x_3,\infty)U...$, where $x_1>x_2>x_3>...$, then their union is $(x_1,\infty)$ which is in the topology?

Comment: @kumhmb: You're off track on the union part. For one thing, we need to consider *arbitrary* unions, not just countable unions. For another, their intersection would be $(x_1,\infty),$ but their union would not.

Comment: So does that sort of method work for proving the intersection of finite many subsets is in the topology?

Comment: @kumhmb: It certainly does, if there are only finitely-many $x_n$ involved. I would warn, though, that it may *seem* like you could use that to prove that countable intersections are in the topology, but that isn't so. Consider the intersection of all sets of the form $$\left(-\frac1n,\infty\right),$$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Basically, we can't assume that a countably infinite set has a greatest element, so the argument falls apart.

Comment: I thought to prove a topology, you only had to show finite intersections are in the topology versus countable.

Comment: @kumhmb: That's true. I just wanted to warn you, since you wrote $x_1>x_2>x_3>\dots,$ that countable sets need not have greatest elements (unlike non-empty finite sets).

Comment: I see. That was my fault. So the best way to write that would be $x_1>...>x_n$?

Comment: That works just fine, yes.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

The set $(a,\infty)$ is the set of all real numbers greater than $a$ and the set $(b,\infty)$ is the set of all real numbers greater than $b.$ Assuming without loss of generality that $a\le b,$ what then is $(a,\infty)\cap(b,\infty)$?

Suppose you have a set $\mathcal A$ of non-trivial open sets--sets of the form $(x,\infty)$ where $x\in\Bbb R$. Each is uniquely determined by its lower endpoint, so if $E$ is the set of all $x$ such that $(x,\infty)\in\mathcal A,$ then $$\bigcup\mathcal A=\bigcup_{x\in E}(x,\infty).$$ What is this union? (You'll need to split into cases depending on whether $E$ is bounded below.)

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I think. But where does the bounded below come into play?

Comment: Would the union be all of $\{bf R}$?

Comment: If $E$ isn't bounded below, then yes, the union would be $\Bbb R.$

Comment: But if E is bounded below, then the union would be $(the bound on E, \infty)$? Is that right?

Comment: If by "the bound on $E$" you mean "the greatest lower bound of $E$" ($\inf E$), then yes.

Comment: Ok, and then since both are in the topology, it satisfies that arbitrary unions are in the topology?

Comment: Indeed, it does.

Comment: You are very welcome.